# The sum of an Arithmetico-Geometric Series implementing permutations

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

I have become stuck on an interesting series which I cannot seem to derive a closed form for, despite its seemingly simple nature.

As a precursor to the actual question, if I were given the series 
$(3)(1)+(9)(5)+(27)(9)+(81)(13)$, I would recognize that the series as composed of an arithmetic series $a(n)=1+5+9+13$ with $d=4$, and a geometric series $g(n)=3+9+27+81$ with $r=3$.  Simple enough.

However, what if the geometric series was actually a permutation?  If I were given the expression $S(n)=(6*5*4*3)(1)+(6*5*4)(2)+(6*5)(3)+(6)(4)$ (assuming that in this case $n=6$), I would recognize it as an arithmetico-geometric series.  In this case, the permutations ($6P4, 6P3, 6P2, 6P1$) would be considered as the geometric series, and the $1+2+3+4$ terms as an arithmetic series.

However, with this all said and done, how would I actually go about deriving a closed form for the sum of this series, assuming that in this case $n=6$.  Is it even possible?!

Note: to avoid any confusion as to what different S(n) series would be, I have included a handy-dandy list below.

$S(7)=(7*6*5*4*3)(1)+(7*6*5*4)(2)+(7*6*5)(3)+(7*6)(4)+(7)(5)$

$S(8)=(8*7*6*5*4*3)(1)+(8*7*6*5*4)(2)+(8*7*6*5)(3)+(8*7*6)(4)+(8*7)(5)+(8)(6)$

Cheers!

Comment: What is the operation between the terms that are enclosed in parentheses? I initially assumed that it is multiplication, but then I see you use the * symbol for multiplication. What is the result of S(6)?

Comment: Try looking at $\frac{S(n)}{n!}$

Comment: @Thanassis The operations between sets of parentheses is multiplication, so your gut was correct.

Comment: @Thanassis S(6) should be $(6*5*4*3)(1)+(6*5*4)(2)+(6*5)(3)+(6)(4)$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\frac{S_n}{n!}=\frac{1}{1.2}+\frac{2}{1.2.3}+\frac{3}{1.2.3.4}+...+\frac{n-2}{(n-1)!}=\sum_{m=1}^{n-2}\frac{m}{(m+1)!}=\sum_{m=1}^{n-2}\frac{m\color{red}{+1-1}}{(m+1)!}\\
\quad =\sum_{m=1}^{n-2}\frac{1}{(m)!}-\sum_{m=1}^{n-2}\frac{1}{(m+1)!}=1-\frac{1}{(n-1)!}=1-\frac{n}{n!}\Rightarrow\color{red}{S_n=n!-n}
$$